# Setting up .NET Core and .NET Standard desktop app for release

Tags: wpf, .net-core, release

Hey there I'm currently working on a fronted for an emulator in WPF (.NET Core 3.1), with a library in .NET Standard. It's quite a long way off done but I would like to get into the habit of making regular builds in the fashion I would like to release them. I'm having a few issues setting up the folder structure in a way that makes sense. With selecting the release profile from visual studio my output folder structure looks like this.

```
<Dir> Assets
<Dir> Runtimes
GameLibrary.xml
PCSX2_Configurator.Frontend.Wpf.pdb
PCSX2_Configurator.Core.pdb
PCSX2_Configurator.Frontend.Wpf.runtimeconfig.json
PCSX2_Configurator.Frontend.Wpf.runtimeconfig.dev.Json
PCSX2_Configurator.Frontend.Wpf.deps.Json
Setting.ini
WpfAnimatedGif.dll
SixLabors.ImageSharp.dll
SixLabors.Core.dll
PCSX2_Configurator.Frontend.Wpf.dll
PCSX2_Configurator.Core.dll
Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Lib2GitSharp.dll
INIFileParser.dll
PCSX2_Configurator.Frontend.Wpf.exe
```

But what I want as a folder structure for distributing in an archive and extracting to the users computer is something more similar to this.

```
<Dir> Assemblies
<Dir> Assets
GameLibrary.xml
Setting.ini
PCSX2 Configurator.exe
```

I would also like my exe to simply be called "PCSX2 Configurator" and show up in task manager as that, while still keeping the assembly and project called PCSX2_Configurator.Frontend.Wpf. Also not 100% sure why I need the generated Json files, should that info not just be part of the executable? I'm sure this level of control (or closer to it) was very much possible with the older .NET Framework, and feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: In the project's properties, if opened with visual studio, you can set the assembly name, (the name of the generated '.exe') without the need to rename the project. If you want to keep the longer name (but not in the task manager) you can rename it in the after build event (still found in the project's properties)

Comment: I'd prefer not to rename the assembly if I can avoid it, I also tried simply renaming the resulting executable that still gives PCSX2_Configurator.Frontend.Wpf in task manager, and that is in the description field of the executable.

Comment: So far I have a partial solution. I was able to figure out how to load the dll files from a sub-folder, and how to change the description to the more friendly name (file can then be renamed obviously). I am still looking for a way of combining/including the runtime information (*.runtimeconfig.json) as a part of the executable.